# XSLT | SAXON | Creating legitimate extension namespace

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I searched google I looked at books and I'm still puzzeled. How do I create real working extension for XSLT2.0 that can be served online. Some guidance is much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    xmlns:my="http://my.working.url.which.serves.the.extension"

    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Solutions with pseudo namespace inside the current scope are not welcome. I'm looking for information about creating legitimate extension such as `exslt` was for XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither with XSLT 1.0 nor with 2.0 nor with EXSLT the namespace URL used loads any code from the domain given in the URL, rather the implementation of the XSLT processor implements the extension. With some extension you can implement them in XSLT itself and then you can `xsl:import` or `xsl:include` to module with the extension. In some cases it is also possible to implement an extension function using a processor specific implementation in a different language (Java, Javascript, C#, VB, PHP) but the code is then also included in an XSLT module or in an additional library to the XSLT processor, it is not served from a URL.

Comment: `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` was under my consideration, but I was wrong about the usage of url in namespace declaration. Thank you for straightening things out for me.